# Pass variable from JavaScript to pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

I'm experimenting with Node.js and MongoDB using an Express scaffold.

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Connect to MongoDB and pull a document out of a collection (this I have managed to do).
2. Display the returned document as html (this is the bit I need help with).

My **index.js** file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, assert = require('assert');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/beetleJuice', function (err, db) {

        assert.equal(null, err);

        // assign the bugs collection to var col
        var col = db.collection('bugs');

        col.findOne({"assignee" : "John Smith"}, function (err, doc) {

            assert.equal(null, err);

            // Print the resulting document to the console
            console.log("Here is my doc: %j", doc);

            // Close the connection to the database
            db.close();
        }); 
    });

    res.render('index'); // How do I pass the doc over to index.jade?
});

module.exports = router;
```

My assumption was that I could pass the `doc` variable by doing something like:

```
res.render('index', doc);
```

However, when I try this I get an error saying that `doc` is not defined.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you're calling 'doc' outside of it's scope. Move res.render('index', doc) just before db.close()

Comment: Thanks @felix, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from [felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6858274/felix) the solution is to move the res.render inside the callback of the findOne function:

```
    col.findOne({"assignee" : "John Smith"}, function (err, doc) {

        assert.equal(null, err);

        // Print the resulting document to the console
        console.log("Here is my doc: %j", doc);

        res.render('index', doc);

        // Close the connection to the database
        db.close();

    }); 
});
```